# White screen in electron when using react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have this typical chart implementation of `react-chartjs-2`. Why is this not working in `electron` generated using `Vite` and with `react` with `TypeScript` (`.tsx`) as the front-end? **The problem:** I can't see the chart, my other components/UI elements disappears when this component is used with other components, the terminal and **the app doesn't give me errors; I just see a blank screen** (image attached below).

```
import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";

const Analytics = () => {
    const data = {
        labels: ["Rent", "Groceries", "Utilities", "Others"],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [8000, 15000, 5000, 12000],
                backgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56", "#4CAF50"],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56",
                    "#4CAF50",
                ],
            },
        ],
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {/* Add the Doughnut chart */}
            <Doughnut data={data} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Analytics;
```

This is what my component looks like before using the component.
**NOTE:** I want to display the chart below the "Hello, World!" text:
[image]
This is what I see after using the component:
[image]

Comment: "the app doesn't give me errors" Are you sure you looked in the *dev* console?

Comment: @Arkellys, Ah, yes! I totally forgot about the dev console. I thought electron doesn't have it. I thought the only thing that's keeping me in check is the terminal (it's my first time trying electron). Thanks! I figured it out now (thanks to the console, lol): I just missed registering some components to the Chart library.